# How to serve (React-)html pages in Spring Boot 5?

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I'm new to the developing with Spring Boot and React. I'm trying to develop a web based wizard application, with multiple forms. Using Spring Boot as back end and React as front end framework. I want to provide a login form and furthermore multiple forms for the wizard task. **Unfortunately I can't manage to make Spring Boot automatically serve my html files to URIs. For example that *test.html* is displayed on http://localhost:8080/test**. **So how can I link (React-)html files to Spring Boot's URIs?**

I've successfully combined React with Spring Boot so that my *index.html* with React content is displayed on http://localhost:8080. So the *index.html* is automatically found and mapped to path '/'. The *index.html* is in the React folder called *public* together with other '.html' files. But only the *index.html* seems to be automatically recognized by Spring Boot. Do I use the wrong folder?

```
- public
     + index.html
     + login.html
     + publicNoSecurity.html
     + ...
 - src
    + main
     + java
         + com
             * ressources
                 - application.properties
             * webwizard.connection
                 - SelfServiceWebwizard.java
 - index.tsx
 - index.css
 - ...
```

When I open for example publicNoSecurity, I got 404 Error:
[no controller -> 404](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqWd9.jpg)

I also tried to implement a Controller-Class with Requestmappings for the URIs. But this also didn't help:

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController 
{
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
    return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/publicNoSecurity")
    public String publicNoSecurity() {
    return "publicNoSecurity";
    }
}
```

With the controller I got the 500 error and a exception:
[with controller -> 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQY22.jpg)

> 2018-07-12 08:35:10.103 ERROR 13560 --- [io-8080-exec-10]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Circular view path [publicNoSecurity]: would dispatch back to the
>   current handler URL [/publicNoSecurity] again. Check your ViewResolver
>   setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to
>   default view name generation.)] with root cause
>
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [publicNoSecurity]:
>   would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/publicNoSecurity]
>   again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of
>   an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:209)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:147)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:314)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1325)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1069)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1008)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:866)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]

You can see the complete code on github: https://github.com/The-Taskmanager/SelfServiceWebwizard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by myself. I missed the '.html' in the return value:

```
@Controller
public class DefaultController 
{
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String login() {
return "login.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/publicNoSecurity")
public String publicNoSecurity() {
return "publicNoSecurity.html";
}
}
```